# Lwc Data Binding not working

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html

Hey Salesforce StackExchange!

I am trying to databind inside of a span but it does not work. I am getting an Undefined Result back, but I can also see that the span has rendered out with data from the chrome dev console. This is happening on onclick={handelBadgeSelected}

Could someone please point me in the right direction and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is the HTML:

```
<template for:each={selectedbadges} for:item="selectedbadge">
                            <div key={selectedbadge.Id} class="slds-visual-picker slds-visual-picker_small">
                                <input type="radio" id={selectedbadge.Id} value={selectedbadge.Id} name="options" />
                                <label>
                                    <span data-name={selectedbadge.Name} onclick={handelBadgeSelected}
                                        class="slds-visual-picker__figure slds-visual-picker__icon slds-align_absolute-center">
                                        <span class="slds-is-selected">
                                            <span class="slds-icon_container">
                                                <img aria-hidden="true" src={selectedbadge.ImageUrl} />
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="slds-is-not-selected">
                                            <span class="slds-icon_container">
                                                <img aria-hidden="true" src={selectedbadge.ImageUrl} />
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="slds-visual-picker__body">
                                        <span class="slds-text-title">{selectedbadge.Name}</span>
                                    </span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </template>
```

And here is the JS

```
handelBadgeSelected(event) {
  window.console.log('Selected Badge Info:',  event.target.dataset.name);
}
```

The Error:
[image: The Error]

Comment: Why are you using `window.console.log`? The window object acts differently in LWC vs regular JS. You should just use `console.log`.

Comment: I built your code in a LWC Playground and it works as expected. I wish I could share it but it appears that SF took that functionality away. What is the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: It just is undefined whenever it consoles.logs I added a screenshot and will add some extra data just to see if it helps.

Comment: I believe the main reason I was using window.console.log was that before it would actually throw errors in vscode before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not completely certain but I believe your problem is coming from the fact that you have a few nested elements. Let's take a look:

```
<span data-name={selectedbadge.Name} onclick={handelBadgeSelected}
                                        class="slds-visual-picker__figure slds-visual-picker__icon slds-align_absolute-center">
                                        <span class="slds-is-selected">
                                            <span class="slds-icon_container">
                                                <img aria-hidden="true" src={selectedbadge.ImageUrl} />
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="slds-is-not-selected">
                                            <span class="slds-icon_container">
                                                <img aria-hidden="true" src={selectedbadge.ImageUrl} />
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
```

In this example you have the parent span `<span data-name={selectedbadge.Name} onclick={handelBadgeSelected}`. However inside of it you have a few other spans and img tags. So when you click on the parent `span` you are probably actually clicking on one of the children and then the event propagates to the parent span. However the `event` is coming from the child which doesn't have a `data-name` attribute.

The way to solve this is to either:

1. Put `data-name={selectedbadge.Name}` on all children OR
2. To use the css property `pointer-events: none;` on the children so you can control where the event triggers from.